# Is it possible to have some intellisense in the Mongoose find method?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to use Mongoose with TypeScript, but I can't figure out how to get some IntelliSense in the `find` method.

Everything is perfect in the response of the `find`, but all fields for the `filter` parameter are marked as `any`...

Is this a known limitation? Or am I doing something wrong?

This is my model definition:

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

// An interface that describes the properties
// that are required to create a new Icd_9
interface Icd_9Attrs {
  description: string;
  code: string;
}

// An interface that describes the properties
// that a Icd_9 Model has
interface Icd_9Model extends mongoose.Model<Icd_9Doc> {
  build(attrs: Icd_9Attrs): Icd_9Doc;
}

// An interface that describes the properties
// that a Icd_9 Document has
interface Icd_9Doc extends mongoose.Document {
  description: string;
  code: string;
}

const icd_9Schema = new mongoose.Schema<Icd_9Doc, Icd_9Model>({
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  code: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

icd_9Schema.statics.build = (attrs: Icd_9Attrs) => { 
  return new Icd_9(attrs);
};

const Icd_9 = mongoose.model<Icd_9Doc, Icd_9Model>('Icd_9', icd_9Schema, 'icd_9');

export { Icd_9 };
```

As you can see the field `description` is marked as `any`...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There has been a few known limitations with TypeScript's IntelliSense and Mongoose. The problem lies in TypeScript's handling of the method overloads for functions like find and other Mongoose query methods.

However, you can improve this experience by doing the following:

- Instead of extending mongoose.Document, provide the desired shape of your document as a generic parameter.
- Whenever you call the find method, you can provide the `type` of the document you're expecting to work with.

Here's an example:

```js
const Icd_9 = mongoose.model<Icd_9Doc, Icd_9Model>('Icd_9', icd_9Schema, 'icd_9');

// When using the find method, provide the type explicitly
const results = await Icd_9.find({}).exec();
```

With the above, the `type` of results should be `Icd_9Doc[]`. However, if IntelliSense doesn't work as expected when typing the filter object in find, then that's an ongoing limitation.
As a workaround, you can use `type` assertions to force TypeScript to recognize the expected shape of the object:

```js
let query: Partial<Icd_9Attrs> = {
  description: "some description"
};

const results = await Icd_9.find(query).exec();
```

This way, you at least have some `type` safety when constructing your queries.